# How to clear or update the content of an element in a grid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I have a WPF window with a grid with 2 rows and some columns with text and buttons, then when I click a button the code adds some rows and populates them with random textblocks and images via for loops. For example, the method I call to add a TextBlock with text s in the (i,j) cell of the grid is

```cs
public void createTextBlock(int i, int j, string s)
{
        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        //Properties
        tb.Foreground = Brushes.Navy;
        tb.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Century Gothic");
        tb.FontSize = 16;
        tb.FontWeight = FontWeights.UltraBold;
        tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        tb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        tb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        tb.Text = s;
        //Add to the Grid
        MyGrid.Children.Add(tb);
        Grid.SetRow(tb, i);
        Grid.SetColumn(tb, j);
}
```

and the method to add an image is similar. The problem is that when I click again, new textblocks and images are added above the old ones and I don't know how to update the content or clear it before adding another.

It is puzzling because the code (before adding rows) checks if the rows are more than 2, and if this is the case it clears all the exceeding rows:

```cs
if (MyGrid.RowDefinitions.Count > 2)
{
    MyGrid.RowDefinitions.RemoveRange(2, MyGrid.RowDefinitions.Count-2);
}
```

but somehow this is not sufficient to clear their content... how can I do it?

**EDIT (to clarify):**

To add rows I use something like this (a little different because there is a switch call but it does not modify the essence)

```cs
public void createGrid(int n)
        {
            //remove rows if present
            if (MyGrid.RowDefinitions.Count > 2)
            {
                MyGrid.RowDefinitions.RemoveRange(2, MyGrid.RowDefinitions.Count-2);
            }
            //permutation  
            int[] permutation = shuffle(deck.Count);            
            for (int i = 2; i < n + 2; i++)
                {
                        RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
                        MyGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
                        row.Height = new GridLength(200, GridUnitType.Pixel);
                        //add image
                        createImage(i, 0, deck[permutation[i - 2]].ImmPath);
                        //add textblock in center column with text chosen 
                        //from a jagged array
                        createTextBlock(i, 1, value[0][i-2]);
                        //add textblock in right column
                        createTextBlock(i, 2, deck[permutation[i - 2]].Meaning);
                 }
```

So the idea is not to add new rows every time but to update the exsisting ones (or add them if needs be, createGrid can be called with different values for n). So I came up with the idea to wipe out the rows exceeding the first 2 (which contains the title and buttons) every time I call that method and add only the needed ones. This is the reason for the first check and RemoveRange.

Comment: why don't you use ItemsControl and skip handle this manually?

Comment: I am new to programming, this is the way I thought I could achieve the goal. If there is a better way I will be more than happy to know it. But still, I'd like to know where is my mistake here and what I am missing

Comment: Ok! Are you adding new RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions? The methods SetRow and SetColumn must match with existing definitions.

Comment: For example: If you have 4 lines and 6 columns the Grid must have 4 RowDefinitions and 6 ColumnDefinitions.

Comment: I think I am doing that, because the rows created are right, the problem is that the new content is superimposed on the old one every time I call this method because RemoveRange apparently removes the rows but does not clear the controls assigned to that positions of the grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you know the row and column of the control you want to remove you could do this

```
foreach (UIElement control in MyGrid.Children)
{
    if (Grid.GetRow(control) == row && Grid.GetColumn(control) == col)
    {
        MyGrid.Children.Remove(control);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added this piece of code (with i and j for row and col) in the createTextBlock() above but it throws an InvalidOperationException error: it says ""Sequence contains no matching element". Maybe because in the first run there is no control in that position? But how can I check it?

Comment: Edited previous answer to provide a better solution. You'll probably still need to add your own logic to make sure you're removing exactly what you're expecting to remove.

Comment: Now it works! Thank you very much :) Sorry but I cannot upvote you because I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this

> It is puzzling because the code (before adding rows) checks if the
>   rows are more than 2, and if this is the case it clears all the
>   exceeding rows

If you are including items that you want to show below the current items, you need to increase the number of RowDefinitions instead of maintain the same.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify that point. I need to add a certain number of rows that depends on the button pressed. The first time can be 7, then 5, then 10, then 10 again... So I need to display (add or update) only the needed rows. My idea was then to avoid complicated cheks and clear all the rows (after the first 2) every time the method is called and then add the rows needed.

Comment: RowDefinitions.Clear = Clear all definitions of rows.
Grid.Children.Clear = Clear all items inside a grid.

Are you removing older items with 'Children.Clear' before create newer?

Comment: No, because I wanted to clear only the controls from the rows after the first 2.